# How to format Culture Currency use method ConvertBack in IValueConverter interface of Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a problem in Xamarin Forms such as:
I want convert number (DataType is Decimal): 12345.2486 to display String on TextBox (Round 2 decimal places after "."):

---> 12,345.25 (en-US)

---> 12 345.25 (fr-FR)

---> 12.345,25 (nl-NL)

I use code after (method in `IValueConverter` interface):

```
public class CurrencyDecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var temp = value as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
            {
                return decimal.Zero;
            }

            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var stringValue = value as string;

            culture = new CultureInfo(App.DeviceCulture);

            stringValue = ConvertCultureCurrencyToString(stringValue, culture);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                return "0";

            return stringValue;
        }
        catch 
        {
            return decimal.Zero;
        }
    }
}

    public string ConvertCultureCurrencyToString(string stringValue, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                return "0";

            stringValue = Convert.ToString(stringValue, ci);
            var currency = decimal.Parse(stringValue, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, ci);

            stringValue = currency.ToString("#,###.##", ci);

            return stringValue;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

I can input on TextBox all the values 12345.2486 (My device is setting language English (en-US)).
But when I input value 0 from the keyboard, TextBox display value String.Empty, i can't input value "0" on TextBox, and when I input very fast value "0.12", TextBox only show ".12". 
Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have a solution to this problem.
The cause of the error seems to be due to the following code:

```
stringValue = currency.ToString("#,###.##", ci);
```

Format "#,###.##" convert value string "0.12" to ".12" in language "en-US"
and convert value string "0,12" to ",12" in language "nl-NL".
So I will add this code after it:

```
if (stringValue.FirstOrDefault() == '.' || stringValue.FirstOrDefault() == ',')   
             stringValue = $"0{stringValue}";
```

And function "ConvertCultureCurrencyToString" will be rewritten as follows:

```
public string ConvertCultureCurrencyToString(string stringValue, CultureInfo ci)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
            return "0";

        stringValue = Convert.ToString(stringValue, ci);
        var currency = decimal.Parse(stringValue, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, ci);

        stringValue = currency.ToString("#,###.##", ci);

        if (stringValue.FirstOrDefault() == '.' || stringValue.FirstOrDefault() == ',')   
             stringValue = $"0{stringValue}";

        return stringValue;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's work. But a little device as iphone5 or Samsung Galaxy S7, etc..., Keyboard of it that can't change language keyboard to language device. So, Case input  character "." or "," will not work.

Comment: @BillNguyen, I will note this case.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a converter to properly format a string to 2 decimal places. In your **binding** for your `Entry`, you can specify a string format. The below code should help you format:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Path=MyDecimal, StringFormat={0:F}}"/>
```

Here is a link to the documentation for it from `Microsoft`:
[Format String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString)

Comment: I think StringFormat={0:F} only use Label, I have never tried using it for an Entry. Thank you for help!

Comment: `StringFormat` works on any control when supplied with a **Binding**. It only makes sense to use it when using a string property such as `Text` which an Entry and Label both have. Buttons would also be able to use **StringFormat** if needed.